How can an estimator be consistent and asymptotically normal at the same time?
I can't work out why the asymptotic distribution of an estimator matters if it is consistent?
My understanding is:
An estimator, $\hat{\theta}$, is consistent if it converges in probability to the true population parameter, $\theta$, as the sample size tends to infinity. My understanding is that in this case then it's variance must tend to zero.
How then can an estimator also be asymptotically normal if its variance is zero in the limit?
I've seen the Central Limit Theorem written in lecture notes as $\bar{x}\overset{a}\sim{N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)}$, but I don't understand how you can have an $n$ left after taking the limit ($\lim_{n\to \infty}$). Surely in this case the variance is zero and the distribution is meaningless.
What am I missing or misunderstanding?

The notation '$\overline X \stackrel{a}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$' doesn't mean the distribution in the limiting sense, rather it shows the distribution of $\overline X$ for large $n$. This is more rigorously written as $\sqrt n(\overline X-\mu) \stackrel{d}\to N(0,\sigma^2)$ as $n\to \infty$. Asymptotic normality in fact implies consistency.

Hi: Consistency means that the limit of the expectation of the estimator is equal to the true parameter. But this doesn't mean that the random variable can't have an asymptotic distribution. The variance only goes to zero if you put it on the RHS but that's usually not a good idea to make the variance a function of $n$. So, generally speaking, suppose $\bar{X}$ has an asymptotic distribution with variance $\frac{1}{n}$ and the limit of the expectation is $\mu$, then we write $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu) \sim N(0, 1)$. This way, by putting the $\sqrt{n}$ on the left hand side, the variance is not degenerate.
